# How to make REST GET in Asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, office365

I can get an access token of Office 365. I can not make a REST request (GET) attaching this token in the header.

I'm using this code:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();
client.EndPoint = @"https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/folders/inbox/messages?$top=10";
client.Method = HttpVerb.GET;
client.ContentType = "application/json";
client.PostData = "authorization: Bearer " + myAccesToken.ToString();
String json = client.MakeRequest();
```

I've tested the access token in http://jwt.calebb.net and it's ok.

But it's always returning:

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I'm kind a knewby to REST and my english is not that good... Sorry! :)

**(RE)EDIT**

I've tried with RestSharp and I've simplified a bit my code...

Now I'm using my access token to make the GET request.

How do I add the "authorization bearer" to my request?

Is it like this?

```
//Ask for the token
var client = new RestClient("https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token");

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
request.AddParameter("code", Request.QueryString["code"]);
request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", myRedirectUri);
request.AddParameter("client_id", myClientID);
request.AddParameter("client_secret", myClientSecret);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string content = "[" + response.Content + "]";

DataTable dadosToken = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(content);
//I don't need a DataTable, but it was a way to retrieve my access token... :)

//Ask for info with the access token
var client2 = new RestClient("https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me");

var request2 = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request2.AddHeader("authorization", myToken.ToString());
//I've tried this way also:
//client2.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(dadosToken.Rows[0]["access_token"].ToString(), "Bearer");

IRestResponse response2 = client2.Execute(request2);
string content2 = "[" + response2.Content + "]";

Response.Write(content2); //this returns NOTHING!
```

Thanks again!

Comment: If you try this request with something like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) do you get any more information back from the service?  Like a detailed reason why you're getting a [400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error)?

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong methods? No? Is there some kind of library that I can use more easily and with better results?

Comment: do you need `$` sign in address?

Comment: @user3330412, I would recommend using RestSharp, but from what I'm seeing from your code, you are already using it. If I am mistaken and you're not using RestSharp, you can give it a try.

Comment: You're going to need the steps you took to get your bearer token in order to have a reproducible problem

Comment: I've (re)edit my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check: Is it a bad request. This usually means the method can't be found or the given parameters cannot be located. Check the deploy and make sure it is the most up to date version and also check that your server is actually running.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Fiddler to figure out if the Request is well formed.
Try a simpler endpoint first like: https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me
and check if the right data comes back. You can call this endpoint just from the browser and also look at the request/respond inside Fiddler.